# Using snprintf with C90

Tags: c, header-files, c99, stdio, c89

Is there a way instruct the the compiler that:

- The *language* is C90
- The *declarations* of stdio.h are those of C99 (including snprintf)

With `cc -std=c90 -Wall` (on a source file using snprintf), an annoying warning is issued (sometimes, depending on the compiler/environment, with a confusing hint that stdio.h should be included, even if it already is), but the linker finds snprintf anyway. I understand what is happening, that is not the question.

Using strict c90 (language) and snprintf (library function) is technically well possible, but I do not know how to instruct the compiler accordingly. In other words, I would like to distinguish between *language* compliance and *library* compliance.

Remark: I assume that the language used in the C99 stdio.h header file is actually C90, and that it could thus be included by a C90 source file. Does anything prevent it?

I would prefer a solution with a generic `include <stdio.h>`, for the sake of portability.

Comment: I don't know all the things that changed between C89 and C99, but would a C99-stdio.h even be language compatible with C89?

Comment: Q: Is there some magic compiler switch to enforce C90 compliance for your "user code", but C99 compliance for headers you include?  A: No such thing exists, nor is it possible.  Q: Will a C99 version of "stdio.h" somehow violate C90 compliance?  A: No.  Q: Will "user code" compiled for C90 compliance be incompatible with a C99 version of the C runtime library?  A: No.  Q: Will "user code" compiled with an old C90 compiler be incompatible with a C99 version of the C runtime library?  A: I doubt it, but it's possible...

Comment: Whether and how this is possible depends on your implementation, so I can't give a proper answer. However, check the documentation for "feature selection macros" and/or "feature test macros."

Comment: @StephenNewell The C99-stdio.h could well be written in the common set of C90 and C99, which is, up to old constructs (implicit int, for instance), quite close to C90. C99 is essentially an extension of C90, and I guess that the extensions are not needed for many functions of the standard libraries of C99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though it's a bit of a weird thing to do.

You can define `_ISOC99_SOURCE` to signal that you want C99 functions to be defined.

Example:

```
#define _ISOC99_SOURCE
#include <features.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[10];
    snprintf(buf, 4, "foo");
    puts(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it like so:

```
$ gcc -std=c90 -Wall test.c  
$ ./a.out 
foo
```

This will work in gcc 10.3.0 and clang 11.0.0. In terms of library compatibility, it has only been tested with glibc, and not musl or other versions of the standard library.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. I do not think it is that weird, many code analysis tools work best with C90, but some library functions (like snprintf) of C99 are useful.

Comment: It also works with cygwin (gcc 10.2.0). Interestingly, features.h was not necessary under linux, but it is under cygwin.

Comment: @Loic WIth glibc, `features.h` is automatically included by every public header, but is not intended to be included directly (if we had it to do all over again we'd probably put it in the "bits" subdirectory).  I am surprised cygwin requires you to include it directly.

Comment: @zwol Interesting, thanks. I saw that stdio.h included features.h, but I assumed that it was an implementation detail that library users aren't supposed to depend on.

Comment: @NickODell Your assumption is correct for glibc, I don't know about cygwin

Answer (score 0):

No.

A generic `#include <stdio.h>` for a C90 compiler needs not declare `snprintf`.

Before you argue that it's not a C90 compiler, keep in mind that you are requesting that it acts as one usng `-std=c90`. A compiler acting as a C90 compiler needs not do anything that a C90 compiler wouldn't do.

There is therefore no generic solution.

There may be compiler-specific solutions, including adding the following:

```c
int snprintf( char * buffer, size_t bufsz,  const char * format, ... );
```

Comment: Works on GCC without the manual declaration. Perhaps because c90 doesn't require a declaration https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r7joY1Gao

Comment: @Ayxan Haqverdili, hmmm, I only get a warning without the declaration today, but I was getting an error yesterday. But the question was about the warning produced by `-Wall` anyway.

Comment: On the other hand, `snprintf` doesn't do anything which couldn't be done in a user-code function that could be portable save for a need to know an upper bound on the length of text that the `%p` format specifier for the implementation's `printf` function might output.